# Unable to publish the 'Last Verified' status in PACT Broker

Tags: gradle, pact, pact-jvm, pact-broker

For microservices contract tests, am using PACT with gradle 4.4 and here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }
 dependencies {
     classpath 'au.com.dius:pact-jvm-provider-gradle_2.12:3.5.22'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: "au.com.dius.pact"


pact {

 serviceProviders {

    // You can define as many as you need, but each must have a unique name
    UserService {

        // All the provider properties are optional, and have sensible defaults (shown below)
        protocol = 'http'
        host = 'localhost'
        port = 8111
        project.version = "2.0.1"
        hasPactsFromPactBroker('http://10.100.198.200:8113')

        }
}            
  pact {
  publish {
  version = "2.0.1"
  pactDirectory = 'pacts' // defaults to $buildDir/pacts
        pactBrokerUrl = 'http://10.100.198.200:8113'

 }
 }
}
```

While am able to publish the pact files in the broker and able to see the dependency graphs, 'Last Verified' shows blank after running the pactVerify method. I saw some documentation around 'pact.verifier.publishResults=true' and tried to pass as gradle parameter, but I got an error message saying:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Your project is misconfigured, was expecting a 'pact' configuration in the build, but got a String with value '' instead. Make sure there is no property that is overriding 'pact'.

the gradle command I run is:

```
      ./gradlew test pactPublish 
      ./gradlew pactVerify -Ppact.verifier.publishResults=true
```

Please let me know what am I missing, the pact.verifier.publishResults is not accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is your Gradle config is invalid. There should only be one `pact` block. You have two. Remove the inner one with the `publish` block in it (but leave the `publish` block :-D).

If that does not resolve your issue, have a look at https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/issues/738 and see if any of the changes from the comments helps.

Comment: Thanks Ronald. the build.gradle was the issue. I had changed it to one pact block and now the results are published to the broker! Thanks for the help :)